# git merge files into working copy

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a git repository where I store template files that I often use, I did a checkout of the latest version a couple of days ago and made local changes to these template files.

I just made  change to the template files master repository and now I want to checkout the most recent version of my master branch but I don't want to have my local changes deleted.

How can I merge the changes from the master branch into my working copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To take full advantage of the merge (or rebase) tactics of git, you could commit the changes to your local repository and then pull. Pull results in a merge between the remote and local repositories, which may be a fast-forward or a recursive merge depending on the upstream changes. You may even want to create a new branch for this (which you can then push to the origin if you want without affecting the master branch).

The stash could help you here, but you run the risk of the stash not being able to apply after the pull.

Simple example:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'My local template changes'
git pull origin master # fix any conflicts
```

New branch example:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git add .
git commit -m 'My local template changes'
git pull origin master # fix any conflicts
```

The latter merges the remote changes in `master` into your local `newbranch`, but bear in mind that in this situation your local copy of `master` would still be behind (i.e. if you then did a `git checkout master` you'd still need a `git pull` to get the changes).

Answer (score 4):

you can always save you local changes in the stash, pull the latest changes and then apply your saved changes again.

```
git stash     -- save your local changes
git pull      -- get latest changes from remote
git stash pop -- apply your saved changes
```

Comment: why is this not straightforwardly done by git merge??

Comment: in other words, why am I required to commit something before I merge? I don't have anything to commit

Comment: I feel like whenever I've tried this, it tells me it can't apply the stash because of conflicts (which it doesn't give me the opportunity to resolve) but tells me it has saved the stash in case I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I came here wanting to know how to do a local `git merge` in the working copy, without making any commits to the branch. The answer is:

```
git merge --squash the-other-branch
```

This stages the merged files (as if they had been added with `git add`), but does not make any commits.

There is also a `--squash` option for `git pull`, which presumably does something similar.